# Should a UI say "My Stuff", or "Your Stuff"?

Tags: usability, text, web, language, typography

I've been getting some different opinions on this question, and wondered if anyone has a well-motivated response. Basically, if I have a part of a website that's called "My something" or "Your something", I feel that it sets a very different conversational tone of the UI.

"My", would mean that I'm the one saying it, meaning in a way I'm taking ownership of the UI as a user. If the menu item is called "Your", then it's the website presenting this area to me, meaning it contains my things, but it's the website that owns it.

I'm personally leaning more towards using "Your", since at least in the beginning of the user using this website the user will not feel at home in the system, making things like "My" feel a bit off. On the other hand, it seems like "Your" is less of a standard approach, so maybe this matter has already been decided and I just haven't found any good resources on it

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Your" vs "My" in user interfaces](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4348/your-vs-my-in-user-interfaces) and related to [My account or your account](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24612/my-account-or-your-account)

Comment: i am one of the user who likes to see "My Stuff" rather than "Your Stuff".