# Geolocation button text

Tags: buttons, maps, title, geolocation

In my website on the contact me page I have a button for showing the users location on Google Map. But I am confused about its text.

Should it be 'Show my Location' or should it be 'View your Location'?

[image]

Comment: My doubt is not whether to use show or view. My doubt is whether it should be my location or your location. And hence it's not about English semantics, rather about ux standard.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, to that point - what does your user gain by being able to see where they are in the world?

Answer (score 2):

Show my location.

See the top answer to this question:
["Your" vs "My" in user interfaces](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4348/your-vs-my-in-user-interfaces)

When users tell the program what to do, use 'my' (e.g. show my location).

When the program asks the user, use 'your' (e.g. do you want to share your location?).