# When refering to the user of an application should I use "You" or "Me"?

Tags: user-expectation, users

I am designing an application where I have a list of items. Some have been added by "You" (the user) and some have been added by your colleagues (everyone else)

To show who has added the item I show the name of the person that added it.

For the items you have added instead of the name I show "You".

But then the question arose. When referring to the user of the application should I use "You" or "Me"

Comment: it's difficult to give a 'correct' answer to this, especially without context. does your application also have usernames? could you use that instead?

Comment: @Midas It does have usernames, But they are Email Addresses. Hence why I have put actual names as I feel it is clearer than an email that could be vague i.e. `CoolDude99@gmail.com`

Comment: makes sense. do you have a mockup or screenshot of the scenario? might give a bit more clarity.

Comment: @Midas I'm sorry I'm not a UX designer, I'm a developer so I don't have any mock ups. I was hoping there was a straight answer. But I guess that isn't the case with UX

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Your" vs "My" in user interfaces](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4348/your-vs-my-in-user-interfaces) or ['My Account' or 'Your Account'?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24612/my-account-or-your-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find this link: https://medium.com/@jsaito/is-this-my-interface-or-yours-b09a7a795256 which gave these guidelines:

> **“My” point of view** By using “my” in an interface, it implies that the product is an extension of the user. It’s as if the product is
>   labeling things on behalf of the user. “My” feels personal. It feels
>   like you can customize and control it.
>
> **“Your” point of view** By using “your” in an interface, it implies that the product is talking with you. It’s almost as if the product is
>   your personal assistant, helping you get something done. “Here’s your
>   music. Here are your orders.”
>
> **When to use me:** Use I, me, my, or mine when the user is interacting with the product, like clicking a button or selecting a
>   checkbox. But only add these words if you absolutely need to for
>   clarity.
>
> **When to use you:** Use you or your when your product is asking questions, giving instructions, or describing things to the user. Just
>   imagine what a personal assistant might say.

So I guess there is no right or wrong answer. But using the guidelines outlined in that article you can deduce your own preference.