# When to use 'View more' and 'Show more'?

Tags: usability, modal-windows

I am using 'Show more' and using modal window to show the hidden content (see the attached image). Do I need to use 'show more' or 'view more'?[image]

Comment: Hey, firstly specify what information you want to convey, then condense it into the smallest and friendly form if after this operation you still have a lot of text, use 'show more'.

It is usually used with a large amount of information

Comment: More context details need to be added to this question. Please read this to know more about how to ask a good question - https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is hidden in this answer to a seemingly unrelated question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/4350/127933

> MS Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines suggests the following:
>
> “Use the second person (you, your) to tell users what to do.” So use second person for error messages, help, window or page labels, on-page documentation, and other places where the app is telling the user about the user’s content.
>
> “Use the first person (I, me, my) to let users tell the program what to do.” So use first person for buttons, menu items, and other controls where the user commands the app.
>
> This means you can have first and second person on the same page. You can label a list “Your photos” but have a button labeled “Publish my photos.”
>
> This is consistent with what a user learns in the physical world, where the reader of text is “listening” to what the creator or owner of the text has to say, so the reader is “you” (e.g.., “We appreciate your business” on an invoice, “Your speed” on a radar speed sign, and, of course, any instruction, like “RSVP”). However, there is an exception for text artifacts that are handled by the reader as a form of communication back to the creator/owner (e.g., a contract, waiver or oath will begin “I, [PRINT NAME], agree that…”). That is like a command button label.

You can think of your interface as a dialogue between the user and the system. When a user clicks a button, they are telling the system what to do. When a user reads a label, it is the system telling the user what they are shown.

If we transfer this sentiment to your question, the correct answer would be *Show more*, as it's a command the user gives to the system when clicking the button.

Comment: Hey, I liked your answer and the way you reached at your conclusion. But I'm confused how `Publish my photos` is different from `view more/show more` here. It is essentially the user telling the system what to do. can we think of it like that in both cases? yes?     
Or do you have any quick hacks to remember how to use first or second person?

Comment: @Kishan thank you for the kind words. You can think of it this way: the user thinks "[I want to] publish my photos" as they press the button. On the other hand, when they are in their gallery, the label can be read as "[Here are] Your photos". Try to complete the sentence as I did with the words in [brackets] to identify *who talks to whom*. In general, buttons most likely describe action, thus require the first person, while labels describe content to the user, thus requiring the second person

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide the content in the box (box-size) according to your design. If the content is out of the box then you should show the `view more` link otherwise don't show the link.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. The doubt here is whether to use `view more` or `show more` and not that should we use a link. You can edit your answer and help everyone. Thank you.